# replacing string text with variables from an array

Tags: php, notifications

I am working on a notification system for a game i'm working on.

I decided to store messages as a string with 'variables' set up to be replaced by the data received through an array.

Example of the message:

`This notification will display !num1 and also !num2`

The array I receive from my query will look like:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [notification_id] => 1
        [message_id] => 1
        [user_id] => 3
        [timestamp] => 2013-02-26 09:46:20
        [active] => 1
        [num1] => 11
        [num2] => 23
        [num3] => 
        [message] => This notification will display !num1 and also !num2
    )
```

What I want to do is replace !num1 and !num2 with the values from the array (11, 23).

message is INNER JOINed in a query from the `message_tbl`. I suppose the tricky part is `num3` which is stored as null.

I am trying to store all notifications for all different types of messages in only 2 tables.

Another example would be :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [notification_id] => 1
        [message_id] => 1
        [user_id] => 3
        [timestamp] => 2013-02-26 09:46:20
        [active] => 1
        [num1] => 11
        [num2] => 23
        [num3] => 
        [message] => This notification will display !num1 and also !num2
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [notification_id] => 2
        [message_id] => 2
        [user_id] => 1
        [timestamp] => 2013-02-26 11:36:20
        [active] => 1
        [num1] => 
        [num2] => 23
        [num3] => stringhere
        [message] => This notification will display !num1 and also !num3
    )
```

Is there a way in PHP to successfully replace the !num(x) with the correct value in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression and a custom callback, like this:

```
$array = array( 'num1' => 11, 'num2' => 23, 'message' => 'This notification will display !num1 and also !num2');
$array['message'] = preg_replace_callback( '/!\b(\w+)\b/', function( $match) use( $array) {
    return $array[ $match[1] ];
}, $array['message']);
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/Wc8Kts) that this outputs:

```
This notification will display 11 and also 23
```

Comment: thanks for such a quick response.  Looks perfect.  I suppose I can set up `$array` by first looking for values that aren't empty?

Comment: Sure if that's what you need to do.

Comment: It seems to work in your demo, but when i put it into my code it returns error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION ` any idea why? -- NVM - my php version was set as 5.2 and it wasn't recognized.  changing to 5.4 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$replacers = array(11, 23);
foreach($results as &$result) {
    foreach($replacers as $k => $v) {
        $result['message'] = str_replace("!num" . $k , $v, $result['message']);
    }
}
```